# Cannot reference this before supertype constructer has been called + Consumer

Tags: java, generics, consumer

I'm attempting to define a generic abstract class that handles the processing/retrying logic of the implementing class. I want all implementing classes to pass a "process" and "fail" function that is executed by the abstract class. The abstract class also holds retry attempt logic and some other generic boilerplate code that I would like to reuse.

Specifically, I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class EnvelopeDispatcher<T> {

    protected Consumer<T> processFn;
    protected Consumer<T> failFn;

    private MetricsRegistry metricsRegistry;


    public EnvelopeDispatcher(MetricsRegistry metricsRegistry, Consumer<T> processFn, Consumer<T> failFn) {
        this.metricsRegistry = metricsRegistry;
        this.processFn = processFn;
        this.failFn = failFn;
    }

    protected void process(T envelope) { 
        //abstract processing logic calling processFn and failFn
    }
}
```

And the following implementing class:

```
public class ActionEnvelopeDispatcher extends EnvelopeDispatcher<ActionEnvelope> implements Consumer<ActionEnvelope> {
        public ActionEnvelopeDispatcher(MetricsRegistry metricsRegistry ) {
                super(metricsRegistry, this::processEnvelope, this::failEnvelope)
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull ActionEnvelope envelopeToProcess) {
            super.process(envelopeToProcess);
        }

        private void processEnvelope( ... ) {
            //processing logic
        }

        private void failEnvelope( ... ) {
            //failure case logic
        }   
    }
```

When I attempt to call super while referencing this::processEnvelope and this::failEnvelope I get "Cannot reference this before supertype constructer has been called".

I understand why this is happening, but I'm not sure of the alternatives. Does anyone know how to get around this or a better implementation pattern?

Comment: I think you can use `super(metricsRegistry, t -> processEnvelope(t), t -> failEnvelope(t))`?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling a (overridden) subclass method from a superclass constructor.

Comment: If you don't access any instance variables from those methods, you can make them static

Comment: @user7 He's not calling methods from the constructor, he's trying to create method references from them.

Comment: @daniu tried that - same error

Comment: @daniu oops. I thought that supplied something to the parent class

Comment: this.processFn = this::processEnvelope and this.failFn = this::failEnvelope DOES work, but its a bit awkward to not have it in constructor.

Comment: I don't think this is a good pattern anyway. The base class has a fine separation of concerns. I'd say that having separate fail- and processhandler classes is better than implementing this functionality in a single subclass.

Comment: @daniu does that still apply if the functionality is desired processing / retrying fucntionality is the same for both subclasses?

Comment: @dgalati54 What "both subclasses"? You only posted one. Even so, if you have two subclasses, it should be even better because you wouldn't even _need_ subclasses. It does depend on your fail and process logic, but from what you posted I don't see how those methods wouldn't be `static` like user7 said.

Comment: If `EnvelopeDispatcher` is an abstract class, `processFn` and `failFn` are provided by a concrete extending class, why don't you make both method abstract and just use normal polymorphism instead?

Comment: @yegodm Thank you - this was what I was trying to do all along. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is don't make the dispatcher abstract and create it using factory methods.

Something like this:

```
class EnvelopeDispatchers {

    // factory method
    public static EnvelopeDispatcher<ActionEnvelope> actionEnvelopeDispatcher(MetricsRegistry metricsRegistry) {
        return new EnvelopeDispatcher(metricsRegistry,
                                      EnvelopeDispatchers::processEnvelope,
                                      EnvelopeDispatchers::failEnvelope);
    }

    private static void processEnvelope(ActionEnvelope env) {
        //processing logic
    }

    private static void failEnvelope(ActionEnvelope env) {
        //failure case logic
    }   
}
```